# Source Location URL mentioned in your add-in's manifest does not exist

Tags: office-js, office-store

This is an Outlook Add-In.  We submitted to the store for validation and were rejected for a reason we don't quite understand.

> The Source Location URL mentioned in your add-in's manifest does not exist. Please ensure all URLs are absolute and final.
>
> `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://outlook-backend.pipelinedeals.com/readmail" />`

The url returns a 200 status code and successfully loads the page with the “Loading…” message. It just never progresses from there because the app doesn’t complete initialization without the Office/Outlook context.

We are unclear of how to proceed and unsure of how to get clarification and help.

Comment: Is it possible the site was down at the time the testing was done? That failure generally means they received a `400` or `500` error of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff,

Thanks for the post. I talked to our validation team and I suspect the URL was not active at the time of testing. If it is working for you now and you can confirm it works in read mode then I'd recommend resubmitting the Add-In assuming you've fixed up any other issues highlighted in the rejection report

If you have any questions in the future please mail osdc1033  AT microsoft DOT com

Thanks
Phil

Comment: Thank you Phil, I appreciate the response -   we will resubmit.